# One-to-Many Navigation Property not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

So I have two tables, users and reviews.  The reviews table has a foreign key constraint on the users.user_key.  I am trying to get the navigation property Users in the ReviewModel to populate.  And also the other way around.  I can't get the ICollection Reviews property in the UserModel to populate either.

UserModel

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int UserKey { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<ReviewModel> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

UserConfiguration

```
class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserModel>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("users", "sec");

        this.HasKey(k => k.UserKey);

        this.Property(p => p.UserKey)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("user_key")
            .HasColumnType("int");

        this.HasMany(r => r.Reviews)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserKey);

        //this.HasOptional(r => r.Reviews)
        //    .WithMany()
        //    .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserKey);
    }
}
```

ReviewModel

```
public class ReviewModel
{
    public int ReviewKey { get; set; }
    public int UserKey { get; set; }

    public virtual UserModel User { get; set; }
}
```

ReviewConfiguration

```
public ReviewConfiguration()
{
    this.ToTable("reviews", "dbo");

    this.HasKey(k => k.ReviewKey);

    this.Property(p => p.ReviewKey)
        .HasColumnName("review_key")
        .HasColumnType("int")
        .IsRequired();

    this.Property(p => p.UserKey)
        .HasColumnName("user_key")
        .HasColumnType("int")
        .IsOptional();

    this.HasRequired(p => p.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Reviews);

    //this.HasRequired(p => p.User)
    //    .WithRequiredPrincipal()
    //    .Map(m => m.ToTable("users", "sec").MapKey("user_key"));
}
```

I have my configuration classes seperated and lets just assume I have the foreign key set up correctly in the SQL database.  Here is my DbContext class where I keep getting errors.

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ReviewModel> reviews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserModel> users { get; set; }

    public TestDbContext() : base("name=TestConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ReviewConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }

    public IEnumerable<ReviewModel> getReviews()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<ReviewModel> reviews = (from r in this.reviews
                                                     select r).DefaultIfEmpty();
            return reviews;
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run this I get this error.

> The navigation property 'Reviews' declared on type 'NameSpace.Models.UserModel' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities.

I used [this link](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration) as a reference and I don't even have the option for HasOne() or WithOne().

If I remove all the navigation properties I can get the DbSets to populate so it's not a database connection problem.

All the commented out code is other stuff I have tried to get this to work.

If I comment out the first .HasRequired in the ReviewConfiguration and uncomment the other one I get this error.

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> user_key: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'user_key' is already defined."

So the question is does anyone know how to set up the DbContext Configuration for a table A that has a foreign key in table B and Table A can have multiple keys associated to a single key in Table B, while table B does not have any foreign keys.

**Update:**
As per Leonardo's suggestion I changed the configurations to...

UserConfiguration:

```
class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserModel>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("users", "sec");

        this.HasKey(k => k.UserKey);

        this.Property(p => p.UserKey)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("user_key")
            .HasColumnType("int");

        this.HasMany(r => r.Reviews)
            .WithRequired(u => u.User)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserKey);
    }
}
```

ReviewConfiguration

```
public class ReviewConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ReviewModel>
{
    public ReviewConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("trail_reviews", "dbo");

        this.HasKey(k => k.ReviewKey);

        this.Property(p => p.ReviewKey)
            .HasColumnName("review_key")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(p => p.UserKey)
            .HasColumnName("user_key")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(p => p.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Reviews)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserKey);
    }
}
```

Now the ReviewModel collection builds, but the User property is never populated.  I checked my database for the correct user_key in each table and the data is correct.  I also added the .HasForeignKey() on the ReviewConfiguration, but with or without it the User property is never populated.

Also the generated SQL query doesn't look right at all.  It looks like it is outer joining the review table on itself???

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[review_key] AS [review_key], 
    [Project1].[user_key] AS [user_key]
    FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[review_key] AS [review_key], 
        [Extent1].[user_key] AS [user_key]
        FROM [dbo].[reviews] AS [Extent1]) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
```

******* Update 2 ********
Ok I put a .ToList() on the IEnumerable I was returning and it had the User property populated.  Somehow it is getting lost when I pass it back to the view, because when I put a breakpoint in my razor view the User property is an error.  So I am going to mark Leonardo's answer as correct since he fixed my problem with the Configurations.

Comment: Also if I use this in the UserConfig for the navigation property
this.HasMany(r => r.Reviews)
                .WithRequired(u => u.User)
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserKey);
It builds the ReviewModel object, but the User property is this error.
((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ReviewModel_C68780366C3573A103F50E8208A4F7DBB06BA9D0D3A9367C1991D66DDC3B27B2)review).User '((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ReviewModel_C68780366C3573A103F50E8208A4F7DBB06BA9D0D3A9367C1991D66DDC3B27B2)review).User' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For review you have
    this.HasRequired(p => p.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Reviews);

That means.. user is required in review.

For user you have

```
this.HasMany(r => r.Reviews)
        .WithOptional()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserKey);
```

That means.. user is optional in review.

Change

```
this.HasMany(r => r.Reviews)
        .WithOptional()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserKey);
```

to

```
this.HasMany(r => r.Reviews)
        .WithRequired(t=> t.UserModel)
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserKey);
```

**Notice the required user model**

and

```
 this.Property(p => p.UserKey)
        .HasColumnName("user_key")
        .HasColumnType("int")
        .IsOptional();
```

to

```
 this.Property(p => p.UserKey)
        .HasColumnName("user_key")
        .HasColumnType("int")
        .IsRequired();
```

Comment: Review has the foreign key related to User.  So Review.UserKey cannot be null.

Comment: Well now the user prop is always null and I checked my db has correct data.  Also the Sql generated query looks wrong.

SELECT 
    [Project1].[review_key] AS [review_key], 
    [Project1].[key] AS [key], 
    [Project1].[user_key] AS [user_key], 
    FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[review_key] AS [review_key], 
        [Extent1].[key] AS [key], 
        [Extent1].[user_key] AS [user_key], 
        FROM [dbo].[reviews] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[key] = 248 ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1

Comment: Did you executed the migration? Update you question with the updated configuration.

Comment: I updated my answer...  this.Property(p => p.UserKey)
            .HasColumnName("user_key")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsOptional(); is required by definition. Please flow the changes in the answer. You have a optional relationship in the user mapping.

Comment: Yeah I updated my original post, I had changed that when I was applying your original suggestions.  Still doesn't populate the User property.

Comment: Basically, you need all your relations required. user -> reviews and review -> user, and the the foreign key review.userkey need to be required too.